# Vectors in a linearly independent set cannot be linear combinations of other vectors in the set.

Tags: linear-algebra

If you have a linearly independent non empty set $B$, vectors in the set can not be linear combination of other vectors in the set. Is this true or false?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Of course it's true.

Answer (score 0):

This is true, it's pretty much the definition of linear independence. Another way to say it is linear independence is when if you have the equation $0 = a_1v_1 + \dots + a_nv_n$ for vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n \neq 0$ then coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_n$ must all be 0. From this you can see that you cannot represent any vector in this set as a linear combination of other vectors in this set.